# How to left-join two tables based on the closest value of their joining attributes?

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

Suppose I have two tables, `t1` and `t2`, they look as follows:

`t1`:

```
id, value
1, 1
2, 1
3, 2
4, 12
5, 13
```

`t2`:

```
id, value
1, 1
2, 2
3, 10
```

I'm trying to left-join the two tables based on the minimum difference between `t1.value` and `t2.value`, such that the result contains all records of `t1` with their closest matching partner from `t2`, so

```
t1.id, t1.value,t2.id
1,1,1
2,1,1
3,2,2
4,12,3
5,13,3
```

I suppose the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value, t2.id
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.value = t2.value -- I don't know what to do here
```

Here are the SQLite queries to reproduce the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "t1" ( "id" INTEGER, "value" INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE "t2" ( "id" INTEGER, "value" INTEGER);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 12), (5, 13);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 10);
```

Comment: You have to tell us--what does "closest matching partner" mean? How could you program this if you can't say? When you do clearly say, this is obviously almost certainly going to be a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Hi philipxy, the join predicate is described in the first part of that sentence -> "left-join the two tables based on the minimum difference between t1.value and t2.value". Is that what you meant with your question?

Comment: "Based on" says nothing & "the minimum difference between t1.value and t2.value" is not clear. You write a bunch of sentence fragments but you don't put them into a clear statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.value
        from t2
        where t2.id <= t1.id
        order by t2.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as t2_value
from t1;
```

Comment: Even though there are three good answers posted so far, this one is by far the most performant one, so I'm marking it as accepted. Thanks to everyone involved!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.value, t2.id
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
ON abs(t1.value - t2.value) = (select min(abs(t1.value - value)) from t2)
```

You join on the absolute minimum of `t1.value - t2.value`. 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qjfppxhVzCbL2jjxGEBg/0).
Results:

```
| id  | value | id  |
| --- | ----- | --- |
| 1   | 1     | 1   |
| 2   | 1     | 1   |
| 3   | 2     | 2   |
| 4   | 12    | 3   |
| 5   | 13    | 3   |
```

Answer (score 1):

Variation that uses the window functions added in Sqlite 3.25 instead of a correlated subquery:

```
WITH cte(id, value, id2, rnk) AS
 (SELECT t1.id, t1.value, t2.id
       , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id ORDER BY abs(t1.value - t2.value))
  FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2)
SELECT id, value, id2
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

which gives

```
id          value       id2       
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           1         
2           1           1         
3           2           2         
4           12          3         
5           13          3
```